# What are the similarities between A3C and PPO in reinforcement learning policy gradient methods?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

Is there any easy way to merge properties of PPO with an A3C method? A3C methods run a number of parrel actors and optimize the parameters. I am trying to merge PPO with A3C.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

PPO has a built-in mechanism(surrogate clipping objective function) to prevent large gradient updates & generally outperforms A3C on most continuous control environments.

In order for PPO to enjoy the benefits of parallel computing like A3C, Distributed PPO(DPPO) is the way to go.

Check out the links below to find out more information about DPPO.

[Pseudo code from the original DeepMind paper](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AYjQN.png)

[Original DeepMind paper: Emergence of Locomotion Behaviours in Rich Environments](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1707.02286.pdf)

If you plan to implement your DPPO code in Python with Tensorflow, I will suggest you to try [Ray](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#) for the part on distributed execution.